# mongodb nodejs driver updateOne doesn't set a new value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to update a mongodb user document. It is as below

```
{
  "_id":"123",
  "email":"sam@example.com"
}
```

I want to add one field 'name' to this document.

My code is as below

```
async function test() {
    const user = {"_id":"123", "email" : "sam@example.com" };
    async function setUsername(user, update) {
      await userCollection.updateOne(user, update);
    }
    await setUsername(user, { $set: { name: "sam"} });
}
test();
```

However, when I see in the db, I am not able to see the field set in the document.

I am sure I am missing someway how the node driver is implemented, but I am not sure of the issue.

I have even tried using upsert: true option which gave me an error as the document was already existing.

Comment: It think you should use `await` inside the async function `setUsername`. So it should be  `await userCollection.updateOne(user, update);`

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet thanks I updated the question. Any thing else that you found to be wrong?

Comment: Convert your `_id` to `ObjectId`.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I don't think that could be a problem.We've been using random generated strings as ids in mongo for quite sometime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I had given the function name wrong and I didn't create the document before.

posting the final snippet that works:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
async function test() {
    const mclient = await MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/?w=1", {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    });
    const db = mclient.db("test");
    const userCollection = db.collection("user");
    const user = { _id: "123", email: "sam@example.com" };
    function setUsername(user, update) {
      return userCollection.updateOne(user, update);
    }
    await setUsername(user, { $set: { name: "sam" } });
}
(async () => {
   test();
})();
```